# cypher retrieve nodes within a specific range time

Tags: time, cypher

I would like to query something like this:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r:PICK_UP]->(g:Grid)
WHERE r.time:[16:00 TO 20:00]
RETURN u.name
```

I read about Lucene’s numeric range query, but i don't know what is the correct syntax for my query

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j does not really support indexes on relationship properties. For this reason you should consider storing the time as a property on a node. You can then use an index supported range query:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:INITIATED]->(e:Event)-[:PICK_UP]->(g:Grid)
WHERE e.time > 1600 AND e.time < 2000
RETURN u.name;
```

These type of numeric range queries are supported by an index beginning in Neo4j version 2.3. Be sure to create an index on the time property: `CREATE INDEX ON :Event(time)`

Comment: Thank you @WilliamLyon, i'm going to try it out. But then, should i store the time like this 1600 instead of 16:00?

Comment: For the numeric range query use an epoch timestamp (for example: `1448309765`) or an integer if you are only interested in hour (such as `1600`)